# How to call classes from a variable variable?

Tags: php, class, methods

I'm not quite sure how to correctly put this question. I want to dynamically call functions that are contained in classes (I think this means they are called 'methods').

Here is an example of my code which I hope helps explain what I am trying to achieve.

In this instance $result returns all the different modules that are loaded. This then checks if the module's PHP file has been included with it's class, then if that class exists - trys to call the class directly.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $moduleclass_name = 'TestClassName_' . $result->module_name . '::FunctionToCall';
    if (method_exists($moduleclass_name, 'FunctionToCall'))
        $VariableToRetrieve = $modulefunction_name($Parameter1, $Parameter2);
}
```

This returns an error

> "Call to undefined function
>   TestClassName_modulename::FunctionToCall()"

although the 'TestClassName' has been declared correctly.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the segment of code where you create the class and method ?

Comment: Also: What is the difference between `$moduleclass_name` and `$modulefunction_name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is probably [`call_user_func_array()`](http://de3.php.net/call_user_func_array).

The code would look similar to this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($classNameOrInstance, $functionName), array($arg1, $arg2, $arg3));
```

**EDIT** Also, in your example you seem to have included the function name in the class parameter for `method_exists`, too...

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func) as such to achieve what you are trying to do. Also, it is better to use [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/is_callable) instead of [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/method_exists) to validate if the method is callable (method may exist but its visibility may prevent it from being callable.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $module_callback = array('TestClassName_' . $result->module_name,'FunctionToCall');
    if (is_callable($module_callback))
        $VariableToRetrieve = call_user_func($module_callback, $Parameter1, $Parameter2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think it doesn't work because your syntax may not support "static method calls".
   I suggest you give a try to Franz's method [`call_user_func()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).
2. I did a similar thing on a former project.

It was designed to call a class which implemented an interface, so method names where known.
I don't think it's difficult to modify this code in order to make it match with yours.

```
class CDispatcher {
    public static function GetDispatcher( $module = 'core' ) {
        $class_name = $module . 'Dispatcher';

        try {
            // looks for the file associated with the class
            // if the file is not found an exception is raised
            search_class( $class_name );
        } catch ( exception $e ){
            throw new UnkwownModuleException($module);
        }

        return new $class_name();
    }
}

// Then, you call this class :
$new_instance = CDispatcher::GetDispatcher( $my_module );
```